# has_many :through relation with one polymorphic and subclassed leg misbehaves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I'm having a tiny problem with the following models (on Rails 3.2rc1). Ownership is mapping Projects and Blogs to Users (Owners) and different types of Blogs exist which handle ownership differently.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projects, through: :ownerships, source: :ownable, :source_type => 'Project'
  has_many :site_blogs, through: :ownerships, source: :ownable, :source_type => 'SiteBlog'
end

class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ownable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owners, through: :ownerships, as: :ownable
  has_many :ownerships, as: :ownable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
end  

class SiteBlog < Blog
  has_many :owners, through: :ownerships, as: :ownable
  has_many :ownerships, as: :ownable, dependent: :destroy
end

class ProjectBlog < Blog
  belongs_to :project
end
```

It all works fine so far, but `SiteBlog#owners` misbehaves:

```
SiteBlog.first.owners
  SiteBlog Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."type" IN ('SiteBlog') LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "ownerships" ON "users"."id" = "ownerships"."user_id" WHERE "ownerships"."ownable_id" = 231145885 AND "ownerships"."ownable_type" = 'Blog'
=> []
```

The problem is the very end of the generated SELECT: `"ownable_type" = 'Blog'`. For this to work, it should be `"ownable_type" = 'SiteBlog'`, however, I don't see how to teach AREL to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a small rails app based on your example. And it works fine.

```
User.create
SiteBlog.create
SiteBlog.first.owners << User.first
```

This creates Ownership record

```
#<Ownership id: 5, ownable_id: 5, ownable_type: "Blog", user_id: 5, created_at: 2012-01-17 20:14:01", updated_at: "2012-01-17 20:14:01">
```

As you see ownable_type is "Blog", not a "SiteBlog". Then:

```
SiteBlog.first.owners
SiteBlog Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "blogs".* FROM "blogs" WHERE "blogs"."type" IN ('SiteBlog') LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "ownerships" ON "users"."id" = "ownerships"."user_id" WHERE "ownerships"."ownable_id" = 5 AND "ownerships"."ownable_type" = 'Blog'
=> [#<User id: 5, created_at: "2012-01-17 19:44:45", updated_at: "2012-01-17 19:44:45">]
```

So - the query is working.

And here's the main part. Look at the activerecord/lib/activerecord/associations/association.rb:

```
def creation_attributes
  attributes = {}

  if reflection.macro.in?([:has_one, :has_many]) && !options[:through]
    attributes[reflection.foreign_key] = owner[reflection.active_record_primary_key]

    if reflection.options[:as]
      attributes[reflection.type] = owner.class.base_class.name
    end
  end

  attributes
end
```

Specifically this line telling that Rails supposed to write base class name - that is Blog, Not SiteBlog:

```
attributes[reflection.type] = owner.class.base_class.name
```

So - everything seems to be fine with your example and with Rails behavior.

Comment: This is just slightly embarrassing :-) It works indeed, a typo caused the problem in my trial app. Time to write specs for this.